# HTML Semantics: div section article, or section div article? Does order matter?

Tags: html, sass, zurb-foundation, semantics

I have a certain way of utilizing sections and I want to know the proper use / best practice for semantic SEO reasons. Which is **better**, **why**, and **is there a better way to do this**?

Is it best to use section THEN a div, vice versa, or is it honestly the same?

```
<section role="title" class="title">
    <div>
        <article>
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

**vs:**

```
<div role="title" class="title">
    <section>
        <article>
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
```

I use the Foundation 6 framework and use semantic SASS to handle my rows, columns, etc.

```
section[role="title"], section.title {
    padding: 100px 0;
    background: black;
    div {
        @include flex-grid-row(); // max-width: 1200px;
        article {
            @include flex-grid-column(12); // width: 100%; or 12 out of 12 columns
            h1 {
                color: white;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully some of you can see why I am asking this. My typical layout is div, section, article / aside. Looking to see if it matters at all.

[HERE IS A CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNEvpK)

Comment: Why do you need that `div` wrapper? Just remove it, and move its styles to `section` or `article`.

Comment: @Oriol cannot remove it. Some sections need to extend full-width with a background, or background color, while keeping the actual content contained within the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer too your question would be to use

```
<div itemprop="name" class="title">
  <section>
    <article>
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
```

If you want to know more I recommend reading up [Here](https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo/basics-of-search-engine-friendly-design-and-development)
You can also use one of googles tools [Here](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/)

Comment: May I ask why itemprop instead of role? I use WordPress, so setting `role="single"` or `role="front-page"` is very handy.

Comment: You asked which would be better to use and 'itemprop="name"' is reccommended over 'role' although they both work